# How to calculate the 3dB frequency from an oscilloscope using a logarithmic sweep?

Tags: filter, oscilloscope, log

How do I calculate the 3 dB frequency from an oscilloscope reading using a logarithmic sweep?

I made the mistake to use logarithmic instead of a linear sweep and now my data don't hold for the formula:

$$f(t)=f_{\text{start}}+(f_{\text{sweep}}/T_{\text{sweep}})⋅t$$

where \$f_{\text{start}}\$ is the starting frequency and \$f_{\text{sweep}}\$ is the starting frequency subtracted from the ending frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the lineair sweep can be calculated from the logarithmic sweep using:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|_{\space\text{dB}}=20\log_{10}\left(\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|\right)\tag1$$

Taking the inverse gives:

$$\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|=10^{\frac{\left|\underline{\mathscr{H}}\left(\text{j}\omega\right)\right|_{\space\text{dB}}}{20}}\tag2$$